# I want to list my uploaded file using partial view mvc,I want to return the entire page without reloading it

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is my post/saving data. I want to list my uploaded file after saving the data.  I already try Ajax.BeginForm but it doesn't support the enctype. I want to return the entire page without reloading it. This is my code saving data :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> AttachmentFiles(string id, HRListViewModel viewModel)
{
    var guid = UrlEncryptionHelper.DecryptId(id);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        List<hr_AttachmentFiles> attachmentFiles = new List<hr_AttachmentFiles>();
        //New Files
        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[i];

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                hr_AttachmentFiles attachmentFile = new hr_AttachmentFiles()
                {
                    HRRecordID = guid,
                    FileName = fileName,
                    Extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName),
                    DateUploaded = System.DateTime.Now,
                    UploadedBy = User.Identity.Name
                };
                attachmentFiles.Add(attachmentFile);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Upload/"), attachmentFile.FileName + attachmentFile.Extension);
                file.SaveAs(path);

                viewModel.NewAttachmentFiles = attachmentFile;
                db.hr_AttachmentFiles.Add(viewModel.NewAttachmentFiles);
            }
        }
    }
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    //return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = UrlEncryptionHelper.EncryptId(viewModel.NewAttachmentFiles.HRRecordID) });
    return PartialView("partialAttachmentFiles", await db.hr_AttachmentFiles.Where(x => x.HRRecordID == guid).ToListAsync());
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want and whats is the issue here?

Comment: I want to return the entire page without reloading the page.

Comment: Then please clearly mention it in the question

Comment: $('#AttachFile').submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/HR/AttachmentFiles',
                datatype: "json",
                type: "post",
                contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                async: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#listAttachments").html(data);
                },
            });
        })

Comment: Okay Thank you @Linga :)

Comment: You can edit your question please add it in the respect code area and update your question accordingly

Comment: Thanks. I already added. @Linga

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to append whole set of model to formdata and obtain it in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc)